# What dependencies are needed to build the dogecoin client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiling, dogecoin

What are the actual dogecoin client requirements?  Their list doesn't seem to match exactly with what I have available, and I had to go back and forth with `apt` to even install what I have so far, and I'm by no means confidence that I have the correct dependencies

```
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ head doc/readme-qt.rst -n 20Dogecoin-Qt: Qt4 GUI for Dogecoin
=================================

Build instructions
==================

Debian
------

First, make sure that the required packages for Qt4 development of your
distribution are installed, for Debian and Ubuntu these are:

::

    apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev \
        libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev \
        libssl-dev libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev

then execute the following:

thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev  libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libboost-dev is already the newest version.
libboost-program-options-dev is already the newest version.
libboost-filesystem-dev is already the newest version.
libboost-system-dev is already the newest version.
libboost-thread-dev is already the newest version.
libqt4-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
qt4-qmake is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a word in your introductory sentence in "I'm by no means confidence that I <?> the dependencies"

Comment: have the correct...dependencies.   You can edit it, Murch, also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somehow or another, I got this to compile.  it was some combination of:

install libboost1.48-all-dev libdb++-dev

then install without version number

then compile, compile fails

blocked packages

start over

install without version number

compile works

I don't remember, but it seemed random.

Much frustrating.

If I knew for a fact the correct dependencies, I would say so.  but, the dependencies for the client and the digger (minerd) are, or might be different, and I was compiling both.

All I'm certain of is that the documentation wasn't correct.

Ubuntu 12.04LTS  (probably didn't help, old version)